Electron App: Production version work differently compared to the development one
I am working with an Electron App. It required an authentication mechanism working as below:

There is a main window which displays almost info including the data and login status.
When the user is not authorized, a Login button will show up instead.
The login function will load the user to a proxy server url in which the users can input their username and password.
If the user input is correct, an successfull message may have returned and then the user will be authorized.

The issue was that I clicked the Login button on the development env, the proxy server window had been poped up so I could input my username and password, however, it seemed to work differently after I had built the application to the exe file as  the Login mechanism automatically had invoked and it showed the success message although I had not input my username and password again.
This is the deps I am using
"dependencies": {
        "@electron/remote": "2.1.2",
        "@emotion/react": "11.13.3",
        "@emotion/styled": "11.13.0",
        "@mui/icons-material": "6.1.1",
        "@mui/lab": "6.0.0-beta.10",
        "@mui/material": "6.1.1",
        "@mui/x-tree-view": "^7.18.0",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
        "clsx": "2.1.1",
        "cors": "2.8.5",
        "cross-env": "7.0.3",
        "date-fns": "4.1.0",
        "dotenv-cli": "^7.4.2",
        "electron-log": "5.2.0",
        "electron-store": "8.2.0",
        "express": "4.21.0",
        "js-yaml": "4.1.0",
        "node-disk-info": "1.3.0",
        "node-stream-zip": "^1.15.0",
        "react": "18.3.1",
        "react-dom": "18.3.1",
        "react-redux": "9.1.2",
        "redux": "5.0.1",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.9",
        "redux-thunk": "3.1.0",
        "semver": "7.6.3",
        "unzipper": "^0.12.3",
        "xml2js": "0.6.2"
    },
"scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "build-electron": "tsc -p tsconfig.electron.json",
        "watch-electron": "tsc -p tsconfig.electron.json -w",
        "start-electron": "electron dist/index.js",
        "dev-electron": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron dist/index.js",
        "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
        "release": "dotenv -- electron-builder --win -c.extraMetadata.main=dist/index.js",
        "licenses": "license-checker-rseidelsohn --csv --production --direct --out licenses.csv",
        "testBuild": "npm run build && npm run start-electron"
    },
"devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "6.5.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "16.0.1",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "14.5.2",
        "@types/express": "4.17.21",
        "@types/jest": "29.5.13",
        "@types/js-yaml": "^4.0.9",
        "@types/node": "22.5.5",
        "@types/react": "18.3.8",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.3.0",
        "@types/react-redux": "7.1.33",
        "@types/semver": "7.5.8",
        "@types/unzipper": "^0.10.10",
        "@types/xml2js": "0.4.14",
        "ajv": "^8.17.1",
        "devtron": "1.4.0",
        "electron": "32.1.2",
        "electron-builder": "25.0.5",
        "license-checker-rseidelsohn": "4.4.2",
        "npm-check-updates": "^17.1.2",
        "postcss-normalize": "^13.0.0",
        "prettier": "3.3.3",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "typescript": "5.6.2"
    },

Please give me some advices if anyone faced this previously.
I want the built exe version works exactly like the one on my development environment.
